# Installing .NET on RedHat

Tags: rhel, .net

Microsoft just released their beta7 version of aspnet yesterday and I'm interested in installing this on a rhel release.  I've been able to install it on ubuntu but the docs for rpm systems have not been sorted out.  As I'm pretty new on unix, brand new on rhel, was wondering if someone could take a look at the ubuntu installation and give me some tips on how I could get it done on rhel.

Docs are here:  http://docs.asp.net/en/1.0.0-beta7/getting-started/installing-on-linux.html

In particular I'm interested in understand how to install the coreclr dependencies:

Running .NET Core on Linux currently requires installing the following additional packages: libunwind8, gettext, libssl-dev, libcurl3-dev, zlib1g

Thanks!

Comment: You can use commands like `yum search automake`, `yum info automake` and/or `yum whatprovides '*libxyz*'` to search for the corresponding rhel packages. Development packages usually have the '-devel' suffix in their names (instead of '-dev'). Otherwise you `yum` is kind of similar to `apt-get` - you can search for the manual/a tutorial.

Comment: so what are my options if there is no yum entry for the version I want?  for instance, I'm looking for llvm-3.5 but yum/rhel only has v3.4 available (whereas llvm.com is up to 3.7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the yum versions I needed:

```
sudo yum -y install libunwind.x86_64 libcurl-devel.x86_64 openssl-devel.x86_64
```

Note that on CentOS minimal, libunwind.x86_64 was in the epel-release repo so this was a prerequisite:

```
sudo yum -y install epel-release
```

Also see here and collaborate, thank you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31855031/how-do-i-install-netcore-on-centos-machine/32571051#32571051

Comment: Thanks Chris!  Can you clarify which version of RHEL this is for?

Comment: I haven't tried this on RHEL, but I have on CentOS 7.1 (1503) and Fedora Server 22.  I hadn't made the effort to get an RHEL evaluation yet, but I'll look at that as well.  I also know that yum is being deprecated, so I'm curious how to changeover, but these are the package names in the yum world where the current docs give them for the apt-get world.

Comment: rhel (at least rhel 6) is so far behind that piecing it together is a pain.  but thanks to your help, it's coming along.  please let us know how you get along with rhel!